# Ajax.BeginForm return result and show data appropriate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have a page as follows:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddAnswer","Marketplace",new AjaxOptions() {HttpMethod = "POST" })){ %>
```

`AddAnswer` action adds some data to db. What I want to do is: when answer has been successfully added, append `#answers` div with the current answer passed to controller. When answer has not been successfully added to db - I would like to display appropriate error in `#errors` div. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I can suggest:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddAnswer(string Value)
{
    // TODO: Try to insert the answer value into the database
    // and return a JSON object that contains the attempted value
    // and an error message if necessary
    return Json(new { Answer = Value, ErrorMessage = "" });
}
```

View:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddAnswer", "Home", 
       new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "success" })) { %>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Value) %>
    <input type="submit" value="Add answer" />
<% } %>

<div id="errors"></div>
<div id="answers"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function success(arg) {
        var obj = arg.get_response().get_object();
        // I apologize for the ugliness that follows, I don't know MS Ajax
        // but this might written better:
        if (obj.ErrorMessage === '') {
            var answer = document.createElement('div');
            answer.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj.Answer));
            document.getElementById('answers').appendChild(answer);
        } else {
            document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = obj.ErrorMessage;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `arg.get_response().get_object();` not working for me. I don't understand why that is not returning the json object.

Comment: @Wale, maybe because I wrote this answer on 22th of April 2010 when Microsoft AJAX scripts were the way to do AJAX in ASP.NET MVC and now it is 2013 (soon to be 2014) and you are using some newer version of ASP.NET MVC (like 4 or 5) where the Ajax.* helpers are using jquery unobtrusive ajax where the syntax is quite different?

Comment: you are quite right. I am new to MVC little wonder I could not tell the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a comment to Darin's answer, but for some reason I can't.
 Basically the OnSuccess and OnFailure events are NOT validating the model, they are just validating that the AJAX call was successful, that it went to the controller and it came back without any errors.
 So, if you want to send error messages from the controller you need to do it just like Darin said, sending a json object and handling it on the onSuccess event.
 You can actually send a List< string> with errors and generate an HTML list in the javascript later, or whatever you need.